# How to document a property in Doxygen if the language only supports accessors?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

In C/C++ I usually need to document a property, not only its accessors (getters and setters). Some documentation systems support this directly, for example, GTK-Doc. But how can I do this with Doxygen?

I describe properties in getters, but it's definitely not a solution. Copying the description in both getter and setter is even worse.

A typical C example, where `Obj` is opaque:

```c
/**
 * Doc for getter
 */
int getSize(Obj* obj);

/**
 * Doc for setter
 */
void setSize(Obj* obj, int size);

// Where to put the documentation for size itself?
```

Comment: Please have a look at \copydoc and its friends. Cann't you use \param for the size argument?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
private:
    m_size ///< Documentation for the property...  
}
```

See the section "Putting documentation after members" [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html). Various other comment formats are specified on that page. You can choose the one that best fits what you already have.